# Dúvida - SQL Server Datas

Tags: sql-server, query, script

No script abaixo quando uma determinada tarefa for finalizada a outra será aberto no primeiro dia útil do mês posterior.

**Exemplo**: A tarefa 10 foi finalizada no dia `18-11-2016`, então, será gerada outra no dia `01-12-2016`. O campo que terá essa data é a `EstTarData` conforme está no script onde coloquei `getdate() + 30`.

**Obs**: Também já tenho uma função de dias uteis calculando corretamente.

## Função:

```
USE [0800net_PRD]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[dias_uteis]    Script Date: 25/09/2017 10:11:39 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION  [dbo].[dias_uteis]  (@DATA_INICIAL DATETIME, @DATA_FINAL 

DATETIME)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CONT INT 

    SET @DATA_INICIAL = (SELECT CAST(@DATA_INICIAL AS DATE) )
    SET @DATA_FINAL = (SELECT CAST(@DATA_FINAL AS DATE ))
    SET @CONT = 0

    WHILE (@DATA_INICIAL <= @DATA_FINAL)
     BEGIN
        IF (DATEPART(DW, @DATA_INICIAL ) IN(1,7) OR @DATA_INICIAL IN (SELECT CAST(FerData AS DATE) FROM Feriado))
         BEGIN
          SET @DATA_INICIAL = @DATA_INICIAL+1
         END

        IF DATEPART(DW, @DATA_INICIAL ) NOT IN(1,7) 
         BEGIN
          SET @CONT = @CONT+1
          SET @DATA_INICIAL = @DATA_INICIAL+1
         END 
     END
RETURN @CONT
END


  

      IF (SELECT TarStatus FROM Tarefa  WHERE TarID = @Tarefa) = 9  
      BEGIN 
          UPDATE EstoqueTarefa SET Ativo = 1 WHERE EstTarID IN (246,569) and EstTarData = getdate() + 30  END  
      END;
```

Comment: Mas no seu caso você está fazendo um `UPDATE`. Está certo isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo @Sorack

Comment: @CaiqueRomero, é update mesmo, é uma regra dentro do nosso sistema. Quanto a função de dias uteis, isso não vem ao caso, só comentei pq existe e queria coloca-la dentro desse script para gerar a proxima tarefa somente no primeiro dia util do mes posterior.

Comment: @CaiqueRomero, editei a pergunta. Coloquei a função.

Comment: @RenanBessa na tabela Tarefa você armazena a data em que foi finalizado?

Comment: Sim @CaiqueRomero, é o campo TarFechamento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criei uma função para pegar o 1 dia útil do mês:

```
CREATE FUNCTION  [dbo].[PrimeiroDiaUtilMes]  (@DATA DATETIME)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET @DATA = (SELECT CAST(DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @DATA), 0) AS DATE) )

    WHILE (DATEPART(DW, @DATA ) IN(1,7) OR @DATA IN (SELECT CAST(FerData AS DATE) FROM Feriado))
     BEGIN
        SET @DATA = @DATA+1
     END
RETURN @DATA
END
```

Após criar a função declare uma variável para armazenar o primeiro dia útil do mês posterior.
Chame a função passando como parâmetro a data de encerramento +1 mês:

```
DECLARE @DiaUtil DATETIME
SET @DiaUtil = (SELECT  dbo.PrimeiroDiaUtilMes(DATEADD(month, 1, TarFechamento) FROM Tarefa WHERE TarID = @Tarefa)
```

Feito isso basta você passar no update do seu `IF` a data armazenada:

```
IF (SELECT TarStatus FROM Tarefa  WHERE TarID = @Tarefa) = 9  
BEGIN 
   UPDATE EstoqueTarefa 
   SET Ativo = 1 
   WHERE EstTarID IN (246,569) 
   AND EstTarData IN = @DiaUtil
END
```

Comment: vou testar aqui e volto pra te dar a resposta. Desde já, muito obg

Comment: Certo, fiz uma correção aqui pois eu havia mudado o nome da coluna para testar rs.. SELECT CAST(FerData AS DATE) FROM Feriado)

Comment: Conseguiu testar? qualquer coisa da um toque.

Comment: tudo certo meu caro. Obrigadão

Comment: tudo certo meu caro. Obrigadão